# Will a brick wall support 150 pounds of mounting bracket and TV?

Tags: walls, brick, television, support

I want to mount a Tripp Lite Model #DWM60100XX television wall mounting bracket that weighs 31 pounds on a brick wall above a gas fireplace in my family room and then hang an 86-inch television that weighs 124 pounds on the bracket.

The mounting bracket is anchored to the masonry with (4) 1/2-inch dia. by 1-3/8-inch long plastic anchors and (4) 1/2-inch dia. by 3-1/2-inch long lag bolts that screw into the plastic anchors.

There are 21 courses of brick above the fireplace where the television will be mounted. There will be 10 courses of brick above the two anchors which are located along the top of the mounting bracket and 8 courses of brick below the two anchors which are located along the bottom of the mounting bracket.

Will the brick wall support this weight?

Comment: Have you checked the temperature of where you want the tv with the fireplace on/burning?  TVs usually do not like heat.  If the bricks are mounted well, it should hold the weight

Comment: "I _want to mount_ a bracket... the bracket _is mounted_" which is it? Is the bracket already up? Is the "Is mounted..." part indicating what the instructions say to do? I don't think there are too many plastic anchors designed for mounting things in brick, and 1-3/8" doesn't seem particularly deep for holding up 150+ pounds of expensive equipment.

Comment: @FreeMan I think the mounting bolts are made out of metal, they are to be screwed into the embedded plastic sleeve. It should be fine if the installation follows the manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: The horizontal spacing of the mount's anchors is important. Vertical spacing? What's the TV's max distance from the wall? Best to embed a picture of the mount. I'd like to see a picture of the brick and it's mortar joints before making even modest assumptions about the mortar. Capturing the wall's interface with the ceiling would be nice to verify that it's braced at the top or instead to suggest that the wall is intermittently tied to something behind it. Maybe it's a structural brick wall? And I can't imagine you know what type of mortar was used, e.g. type S? The bricks are 4" thick?

Comment: Here's its data sheet: https://assets.tripplite.com/product-pdfs/en/dwm60100xx.pdf

Comment: Max distance from the wall is about 2 feet judging from that data sheet.  I'd be looking for all metal anchors given that the pull-out force on the upper anchors will be hundereds of pounds with the arm extended and that this may be a hot location.  speak to a mason about how strong the bricks will be. divide arm length (24") by the height between bottom and top anchors (3 courses of brick? - seems small?)  to get the weight multiplication factor for pull-out force on the (combined) top anchors

Comment: @r13 my point was using a plastic anchor with a metal screw/bolt in a masonry wall seems... sketchy. Of course, I wouldn't use a plastic anchor for attaching this thing to drywall/plaster & lath, either, unless it was for maybe one pair of bolts that didn't hit a stud, but then, that wouldn't be adding much strength. Most anchors for masonry of any type are all metal. I'm questioning whether these plastic anchors are designed for a masonry install at all. Maybe the OP missed something in the instructions about their appropriate use?

Comment: For what it’s worth, the install instructions specify the plastic sleeve anchors in the bricks (not mortar). They also feature the weasel-y ‘… installer is responsible for ensuring adequate attachment’. If I was doing this, I’d bring extra fasteners — they only supply 4.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree that the metal-plastic mix does not offer confident.

Comment: The critical question for me is how the brick is attached to the substrate. You haven't mentioned that. Brick under load from above is very stable. A facade stuck to a wall inside, not so much.

Comment: **A swivel mount ?**  You need to model a 125 lb TV at the end of the swivel arm fully extended, then a human grabbing a corner of the 85 inch TV, 43 inches further out from the arm, and using their body weight to manipulate the TV, inelegantly, into position.  How does that translate to forces and vibrations on your mounting screws?  How is the wall constructed?  Is it a real load-bearing brick wall?  If it's a facade what is the actual structure?   *Please* consider a fixed mount.  It will make this question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Metal screws in plastic anchors are common here in the UK, where we generally have masonry walls.  For heavy loads or those with long lever arms, I'm tending towards screws that cut a thread into the wall, like [Heco Multi Monti](https://www.phstore.co.uk/direct-masonry-fixings/), partly because my dry-lining means the bracket or whatever is already 40mm from the brick/concrete, and those things are both long and stiff

Comment: @Jay or an armless swivel mount, to allow angle adjustment, fixed with serious machine screws into a serious (but minimal length to allow the angle to be made) metal spacer, that in turn is fixed with a serious number of serious fasteners deep into the bricks

Comment: @ChrisH I think all fixed mounts allow some vertical angle adjustment.  I don't like TVs over fireplaces to begin with ... mounting one there that also requires horizontal angle adjustment is getting comical.  But ya I agree .. as long as end users cannot routinely modify the mount, the challenge is a lot lower.

Comment: @jay613 possibly. I was thinking of the horizontal angle. As my TV is 36", on a table, and not currently plugged in, I can't claim to be an expert. But the slim things we've used in work have a few degrees in each axis and that's nice to have (not that they're up to this weight)

Comment: @ChrisH Aside from the safety issues of having end-users, possibly children, manipulate such a large heavy object on a swing arm, I think if you're placing a monumental TV over a fireplace, the room should be designed around that arrangement.  There can be no other purpose to the room.  If people need to move the TV in order to see it, you've combined a bad idea with a terrible implementation.

Comment: @jay613 I agree, which is why I'm arguing against anything with an arm, and in favour of sitting it as close to the wall as possible. But one-off adjustment, or even just setting it on a slight angle may be needed in many rooms.  At least if it's over a fireplace that puts it some distance off the floor and (without sticking out on an arm) away from casual prodding and grabbing.

Comment: Under ACI 530, an unreinforced brick wall's bending strength is predicated on the mortar type. This provides the Fb for -P/A + M/S < Fb. Without boundary conditions (is it periodically tied back to a wood wall under IRC requirements? Is it a floor to ceiling structural wall with 2 wythes? Etc.), it's impossible to say if your eccentric TV's weight over-stresses the wall. Additionally there's a punching shear failure mode to check where the individual bricks with anchors pull out of the wall under too much load. You need to provide a picture of the brick install and some further info.