# Mounting TV on brick over fireplace

Tags: mounting, fireplace, brick, television

Yes I am aware that if the fireplace is used, the higher temperatures are bad for the TV. I'm also aware that this is an uncomfortable viewing angle.

This person wants the TV mounted above the fireplace. What's the best way to mount How could I tell if this is real brick or just a facade? If it's a facade, it would be mounted to plywood or cement board so toggle anchors will be sufficient? If real brick - expanding sleeve anchors through the mortar joints?
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Are you removing the mantelpiece? That will affect your options. But in general I would mount plywood (painted white) to brick and then VESA TV mount to plywood and TV to VESA.

Comment: I believe the mantelpiece would be staying. How would you mount the plywood to the brick though?

Comment: Or this? [Mounting a TV above a fireplace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189272/mounting-a-tv-above-a-fireplace)

Comment: Or this? [Will a brick wall support 150 pounds of mounting bracket and TV?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/292953/35141)

Comment: It should be fairly apparent whether it's real brick behind the face frame.

Comment: What kind of mount? The ones that swing away from the wall can exert significant withdrawal forces. The ones that mount tight to the wall are no big deal. The sleeve anchors work nice in mortar joints. There are deep lag shields that also work well in mortar joints, but the required hole diameters are probably a deal killer.

Comment: @isherwood what do you mean by face frame? The frame of the fireplace insert?

Comment: @popham no specific mount just yet. I'm finding a lot of mixed opinions on how to best install sleeve anchors - in the middle of the brick vs the mortar. Also is there an easy way to identify if this is just a veneer or actual brick? The photos do show significant depth to the brick but those may just be veneer outside corner pieces?

Comment: Can you see the edge of the brick from inside the firebox? I would expect to see the thin brick edges if that's what you're dealing with. Even if they make corner pieces for along the top of the opening, I wouldn't expect an installer to bother maintaining the illusion for people sticking their heads inside the firebox.

Comment: In my experience, if its well constructed modern fireplace, the TV does not get hot. In our last place, we had a timber mantlepiece, yet the Council dictated that a heat deflector be installed. It was a thin sheet of polished metal hanging via offsets under the timber. In retrospect, it wasn't required.

Comment: The brass door assembly. That doesn't look like an insert to me, but it's not clear from these photos.